# Looking for a way to iterate files and conditionally import variables from those files in Python

Tags: python, import, tkinter

I've actually managed the first part (iterating thru files). It's the second part (importing variables from iterated files) where I'm stuck. Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
import os, sys
for file in os.listdir ():
    if "py" in file.split ("."):
        counter = 0
        for line in open (file):
            if "name = " in line:
                counter += 1
            if "profile = [" in line and counter == 1:
                from file import name
                people_list.add_command(label=name,command=get_people)
```

In case it wasn't obvious, this is meant to dynamically generate tkinter menu choices from python files.

I realize that the variable "file" can't work in the "from/import" statement because it contains the filename with the .py extension. I'd like to find some easy way to substitute the filename minus the extension here after each iteration to allow importation.

I reckon I could accomplish this by getting a little more fancy with string slicing or reg-ex instead, and not even bother with importation. But is there some "minimally-invasive" way to modify my existing code to work?

Comment: You don't need to use two if conditions, you can simply nest them in each other

Comment: the easiest way to get rid of `.py` extension from a given file name is using string slicing like : `file_name[:-3]`

Answer (score 0):

Edit the path name as per your working directory and then you can easily implement this code , I have only fixed the import issue in this code, So take care of other methods and functions if they raise any errors

```
import sys,os

PATH = r'C:\\Users\\Anmol\\Desktop\\image peocessing\\'

for file_name in os.listdir(PATH):
    if ".py" in file_name:
        counter = 0
        for line in open(file_name):
            if "name = " in line:
                counter+=1
            if "profile = [" in line and counter == 1:
                from file_name.split(".")[0] import name
                #You could have used simple string slicing file_name[:-3] but that will not work if 
                #you have .pyc files in your folder, So this is a more robust approach .
                people_list.add_command(label=name,command=get_people)
```